# How to install ET-2600Printer

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I have never used Ubuntu before and purchased a Dell pc with it installed, after being recommended by my brother who has now passed away. I have no idea what I'm doing but I'm attempting to get it to talk to my printer, without success, so far.

Using the add printer function I have added a ppd file for this printer, from the Epson website, which in itself was confusing as 6 folders came up for download, all having warnings on them to say that they would damage my pc. It still has a warning exclamation mark next to the icon for this printer and I'm attaching a screenshot for this.

Please can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you try remove and reinstall the printer again, it seems you have installed it but there are missing components, thus the printer are not expected to work.

Comment: Delete the printer from **Printers** program, then add again.

Comment: OK, thank you. I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: I'm still getting the same message asking for '/usr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper'

Comment: It seems you're missing the required driver, try `sudo apt install printer-driver-escpr`, and report back.

Comment: Hi @Janlee, do you able to successfully install the printer ?

Comment: Oh my goodness. I didn't give up. Tried again today and  It works - thank you so much!

Comment: I already posted an answer knowing you able to solved this, please do [accept the answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer), but either way its fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture of your post, I see that the printer program complaints about missing components, making the printer unusable. So I ask you to add/reinstall the printer once again, to make sure the step you went is correct.

You replied things doesn't change even after reinstalling the printer, furthermore you reported the error.

```
/usr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper
```

This is the printer filter meant in the warning, and if it is missing, this **calls** for missing driver. I dig around and found this file provided by package `printer-driver-escpr`. Simply installing should fix the problem.

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-escpr
```